# The yuga's- their repetition

Tags: yuga

I have read that kaliyuga is the last yuga which will end with catatrophism, and then again satyuga will start, 
Now my question is is this tetrad (of satyuga, tretayuga, dwaperyuga, kalyuga) was the first one or there were early kaliyugas also

Comment: There are many kalyuga has been passed till now. In one of the prev. Kal yuga, Vishnu took incarnation (Matasya avatar). He took incarnation at the end of kalyuga.